# What is the difference between XSLT attributes when and if

Tags: xml, xslt

What is the difference between two given below codes? Both codes checks whether an attribute exists in a tag or not:

```
<xsl:choose>
  <xsl:when test="string-length(DBE:Attribute[@name='s0SelectedSite']/node()) &gt; 0"> 
    <table>
        ...
    </table>
  </xsl:when>
  <xsl:otherwise>
    <table>
        ...
    </table>
  </xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
```

and

```
<xsl:if test="@Col1-AllocValue"> 
    <xsl:copy-of select="@Col1-AllocValue"/>
</xsl:if>
```

Answer (score 19):

Structure of choose is

```
<xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="a">A</xsl:when>
    <xsl:when test="b">B</xsl:when>
    <xsl:when test="c">C</xsl:when>
    <xsl:when test="...">...</xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>Z</xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
```

which allows multiple checks and one operation to be performed for the first test evaluating to `true`. `xsl:otherwise` is for performing default actions when none of the checks evaluates to `true`; in particular this facilitates an if-then-else construction (just one `xsl:when` alternative plus an `xsl:otherwise` block).

It always astounded me that `xsl:if` did not allow for an `xsl:else` alternative, but as this is available in `xsl:choose` construct, I guess it was judged not to add it. Maybe the next XSLT version will incorporate an `xsl:else`?

For the rest, the tests in `xsl:when` and in `xsl:if` do exactly the same thing: check the condition.

Note that the structure of `xsl:if` is simply

```
<xsl:if test="a">A</xsl:if>
```

A single

```
<xsl:when test="a">A</xsl:when>
```

would be invalid: `xsl:when` element is **always** a child of `xsl:choose`. And `xsl:choose` may have children `xsl:when` and `xsl:otherwise` only.

Answer (score 5):

The `choose` allows you to test for multiple conditions and apply only when one matches (or a default case). With `if` you can test too, but they are tested independently and each matching case will have output.

Adding more details (sorry had to rush off)

`choose` allows you to test for multiple cases and only generate output in the case that one of the conditions match, or generate some default output. for example:

```
<xsl:choose>
  <xsl:when test='@foo=1'><!-- do something when @foo is 1--></xsl:when>
  <xsl:when test='@foo=2'><!-- do something when @foo is 2--></xsl:when>
  <xsl:when test='@foo=3'><!-- do something when @foo is 3--></xsl:when> 
  <xsl:otherwise><!-- this is the default case, when @foo is neither 1, 2 or 3--></xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
```

As you can see **one** of the "branches" **will be** taken depending on the value of `@foo`.

With `if`, it's a single test and generate output on the result of that test:

```
<xsl:if test='@foo=1'><!-- do this if @foo is 1--></xsl:if>
<xsl:if test='@foo=2'><!-- do this if @foo is 2--></xsl:if>
<xsl:if test='@foo=3'><!-- do this if @foo is 3--></xsl:if>
```

The complication here is the *failure case* - what happens when `@foo` is neither 1,2 or 3? This missing case is what is handled neatly by the `choose` - i.e. the ability to have a *default* action.

XSL also lacks the "else" that you find in most other languages, that allows you to provide an alternative action should the `if` test fail - and a `choose` with a single `when` and `otherwise` allows you to get around this, but in my example above, that would be horrible (to demonstrate why you would not do this..)

```
<xsl:choose>
  <xsl:when test='@foo=1'><!-- do something when @foo is 1--></xsl:when>
  <xsl:otherwise> <!-- else -->
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test='@foo=2'><!-- do something when @foo is 2--></xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise> <!-- else -->
        <xsl:choose>
          <xsl:when test='@foo=2'><!-- do something when @foo is 2--></xsl:when>
          <xsl:otherwise><!-- this is the case, when @foo is neither 1, 2 or 3--></xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
      </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
```

Answer (score 1):

> What is the difference between two given below codes? Both codes
>   checks whether an attribute exists in a tag or not:

**This isn't true**:

1. The first code fragment expresses an *if ... then ... else* action, while the second fragment expresses just an *if ...* action.
2. The conditions tested for in the provided two code fragments -- within the `xsl:when` instruction and withinin the `xsl:if` instructions are different. In fact only the `xsl:if` (in the second code fragment) tests for existence of an attribute.